# ¿Cómo podría mostrar los CountryRegion con mayor subtotal?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

```
select distinct a.CountryRegion,c.CompanyName,soh.SubTotal from SalesLT.Address a
inner join SalesLT.CustomerAddress CA on a.AddressID = CA.AddressID
inner join SalesLT.Customer C on C.CustomerID = CA.CustomerID
inner join SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader SOH on C.CustomerID = SOH.CustomerID
inner join SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail SOD on SOH.SalesOrderID = SOD.SalesOrderID
inner join SalesLT.Product P on P.ProductID = SOD.ProductID;
```

**Tabla :**

| CountryRegion | CompanyName | SubTotal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| United States | Extreme Riding Supplies | 57634.6342 |
| United Kingdom | Action Bicycle Specialists | 108561.8317 |
| United States | Eastside Department Store | 83858.4261 |
| Canada | Nearby Cycle Shop | 6634.2961 |
| Canada | Engineered Bike Systems | 3398.1659 |
| United Kingdom | Bulk Discount Store | 88812.8625 |

**Resultado deseado :**

| CountryRegion | CompanyName | SubTotal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| United Kingdom | Action Bicycle Specialists | 108561.8317 |
| United States | Eastside Department Store | 83858.4261 |
| Canada | Nearby Cycle Shop | 6634.2961 |

Answer (score 1):

Puedes agrupar y hacer un MAX sobre el subtotal:

```
SELECT
    a.CountryRegion,
    c.CompanyName,
    MAX(soh.SubTotal) as Subtotal
FROM
    SalesLT.Address a inner join SalesLT.CustomerAddress CA on a.AddressID = CA.AddressID
    inner join SalesLT.Customer C on C.CustomerID = CA.CustomerID
    inner join SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader SOH on C.CustomerID = SOH.CustomerID
    inner join SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail SOD on SOH.SalesOrderID = SOD.SalesOrderID
    inner join SalesLT.Product P on P.ProductID = SOD.ProductID
GROUP BY a.CountryRegion, c.CompanyName
ORDER BY SubTotal DESC
```